# In MQTT, can i send a message to single client? Or only in a topic?

Tags: mqtt

I have an application using MQTT, with clients connected on various topics, however, I have the need to send a message only to a client, not to an entire topic. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, MQTT is a pub/sub protocol, messages are published on topics and there may be 0 to many subscribers to that topic

The closest you can do is pick a topic that you know only the client you want will be subscribed to.